# Unable to import OpenCV in python3.6 on mac OSX, is this a dependency issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, python-import, importerror

Iam having the below error while importing opencv in a face recognition project

import cv2
  File "/Users/vijaykumar/Desktop/face_recogproj/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/**init**.py", line 3, in 
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/vijaykumar/Desktop/face_recogproj/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _inflateValidate
  Referenced from: /Users/vijaykumar/Desktop/face_recogproj/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/libpng16.16.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
 in /Users/vijaykumar/Desktop/face_recogproj/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/libpng16.16.dylib

Answer (score 0):

Installing OpenCV on macOS has many steps.

I hope you have done this `brew install jpeg libpng libtiff openexr`

You can follow this [link](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/17/install-opencv-4-on-macos/) for the complete guide to install OpenCV 4 on macOS:

For [OpenCV 3](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/05/macos-install-opencv-3-and-python-3-5/)